# What is Ansible's config equivalent of `--vault-password-file`?

Tags: ansible

According the help of ansible-playbook one could use `--user=REMOTE_USER` to define the ssh user, but one could also define `ansible_ssh_user: REMOTE_USER` in either the host- or group_vars.

**Question**

What variable need to be defined in either the group- or host_vars directory to prevent that `--vault-password-file` has to be defined while running `ansible-playbook`?

**Attempts**

- When `ansible_vault_password_file: ~/.vault_pass.txt` is defined in the config the decryption fails:

  ```
  ERROR! Decryption failed on /path/to/vault
  ```
- No associated vault variables was found in [this documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html)

Comment: Btw it's now documented (from version 1.7) here: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html#vault-password-file

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/constants.py) is the definition:

```
DEFAULT_VAULT_PASSWORD_FILE = get_config(p, DEFAULTS, 'vault_password_file', \
'ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD_FILE', None, value_type='path')
```

---

This means that you either put in ansible.cfg or playbook:

```
vault_password_file: ~/.vault_pass.txt
```

Or in your shell defined this variable:

```
export ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD_FILE=~/.vault_pass.txt
```

Comment: @JiriKlouda it does not seem to work although it has been defined in `group_vars/all/vars`. `export ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD_FILE=~/.vault_pass.txt` had to be run.

Comment: This is a config variable. It has to be in ansible.cfg or equivalent or in the playbook.

Comment: Also I have specifically checked the 2.2 version you run and it is there: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/stable-2.2/lib/ansible/constants.py#L175

Comment: When I export the variable it works

Comment: @JiriKlouda it's best to include the actual answer, not just the link, because links become invalid over time, and a direct answer is more useful too.

Comment: Sometimes that is the case, but when you point to a github repository of the project, that is being up to date as long as the project is being developed and relevant and if it goes out of date, it means the project is no longer relevant and the answer itself does not matter. In such case a link is better than a copy of answer which could itself become stale.

Comment: The docs say that DEFAULT_VAULT_PASSWORD_FILE can be used in the config. I'm running Ansible 2.10.1 and this doesn't work. But your clarification (from code) that it should actually be `vault_password_file` specified in the config fixed the situation for me.

Answer (score 3):

You can set an environment variable `ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD_FILE` storing the path the the vault password file. This way you won't have the always use the `--vault-password-file` switch when running a playbook.

This is described in Ansible's Vault documentation, available [here](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_vault.html).

So, add `export ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD_FILE=~/.vault_pass.txt` to your `~/.bash_profile`, source from it and you're ready to go.

If you need different vault passwords for different groups of hosts, then you should do the following:

> Inside of this subdirectory,
>   create two files named vars and vault. Inside of the vars file, define
>   all of the variables needed, including any sensitive ones. Next, copy
>   all of the sensitive variables over to the vault file and prefix these
>   variables with vault_. You should adjust the variables in the vars
>   file to point to the matching vault_ variables and ensure that the
>   vault file is vault encrypted.

This is an example for best practices approach for managing sensitive information on per group basis. More information is available in Ansible's documentation [here](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_best_practices.html#best-practices-for-variables-and-vaults) (The above text is copied from there).

Comment: This won't allow a different password per hosts

Comment: Are you referring to connection password? Because if you do, what does it have in common with Ansible Vault?

Comment: I was referring to the vault password, willing to have different vault password for different groups makes sense (and is the root of the question as far as I understand it).

Comment: I didn't understand it that way. I've edited my answer to include that scenario.

Comment: seems better. Btw downvote is not mine

Comment: `export ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD_FILE=~/.vault_pass.txt`