# Why could the encrypted Ansible files not be decrypted although the vault password file has been set?

Tags: ansible-vault

Follow-up to this [Q&A](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/703/210).

According to this and this documentation it should be possible to define a default vault password file by specifying `vault_password_file = ~/.vault_pass.txt` in one of the following files:

> ```
> * ANSIBLE_CONFIG (an environment variable)
> * ansible.cfg (in the current directory)
> * .ansible.cfg (in the home directory)
> * /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
> ```

Although the password file exists and the log indicates that the ansible.cfg is used that contains the definition, the decryption fails:

```
user@host$
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
ERROR! Decryption failed on /path/to/ansible/group_vars/production/vault
```

**Discussion**

- > Is the pass correct for this vault?

Yes. When ansible is run using `--vault-password-file=~/.vault_pass.txt` the decryption succeeds.

- > Just so that we're clear - the name of the environment variable is `ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD_FILE`, correct?

No. When this variable is used it works, but the aim is to set it in the ansible.cfg by setting `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg`.

- > What Ansible version is used?

  ```
  user@host:/dir$ ansible --version
  ansible 2.2.2.0
      config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
      configured module search path = Default w/o overrides
  ```
- > Does using a full path in the config works?

The decryption failes as well when the full path instead of `~`, i.e. `/home/user/.vault_pass.txt` was specified.

Comment: Just so that we're clear - the name of the environment variable is `ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD_FILE`, correct?

Comment: And what's the output of `echo $ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD_FILE`?

Comment: it is empty because I try to use `vault_password_file = ~/.vault_pass.txt`

Comment: variable names are case sensitive

Comment: This is set in the ansible.cfg. I am not using an environment variable

Comment: Definitely a strange scenario. Do you have any other non-default variables in /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg that *are* being set correctly? And to confirm, you ran this in full verbosity (-vvv) and there is no additional output between "Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file" and "ERROR", right? I couldn't find this exact issue in Github, but even without a smoking gun, consider trying this in Ansible 2.3

Comment: Are you using the ```vault_password_file = /path/to/file``` under ```[defaults]``` in your config file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear why it failed, but setting `vault_password_file = ~/.vault_pass.txt` in `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg` was sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

I found an issue with Ansible/Python causing a failure to decrypt.

Specifically, Ansible 2.7.10 and 2.7.13 under Python 3.6.8 on Ubuntu 18.04 would not decrypt (using `ansible-vault edit -vvvvv`) a vault file that was identical to file that decrypted OK on macOS 10.13 using Python 3.7.2 with same Ansible versions.

Upgrading to Python 3.7.3 on Ubuntu (using `apt-get install python3.7` on 18.04) fixed this.

Your issue may be different, but if on Python 3.6 or lower, I would try upgrading to 3.7.

Comment: I can confirm a similar behavior: I started an `ansible` project using python3.* in a virtual environment on OSX; I then cloned it onto an Ubuntu 20.04LTS machine and started using the `vault-keyring-client.py` script to pull my vault password from my system keyring, so I didn't have to store it at rest (https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.general/blob/main/scripts/vault/vault-keyring-client.py) I configured it properly, and encrypted and then viewed a file with `ansible-vault`, but simply viewing or decrypting strings/files encrypted on OSX threw an HMAC verification failure.

Comment: I guess I need to re-encrypt all the files and strings that were originally encrypted on the OSX machine.  I am using a `pyenv` python 3.* in a virtual environment on both machines, so I'm a little confused

Comment: @Life5ign Interesting - which versions of Python are you using on macOS and Ubuntu?  If not the same, can you try 3.7 on both?  This would help diagnose if it's a Python version issue or macOS vs Ubuntu difference.

Answer (score -1):

According to the [docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_vault.html),

> You can also set ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD_FILEenvironment variable, e.g. ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD_FILE=~/.vault_pass.txtand Ansible will automatically search for the password in that file.

Ensures that you are using the exact same case.

Comment: You are'missing the question, it is about configuration file property specially, it is stated literally in the question, read it again carefully